# Can a race condition occur when executing such code on Julia?

Tags: multithreading, julia, race-condition

I have a function below. Can a race condition occur when executing such code?

```
function thread_test(v)
  Threads.@threads for i = 1:length(v)
      @inbounds v[i] = rand()
  end
  sum(v)
end
```

Comment: Suspiciously very similar to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74685850) asked nearly at the same moment but with a different account.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `v` is an `Array` there will be no race condition. Accessing different array elements in different threads is safe.

However, if `v` is e.g. a `Dict{Int, Float64}` you can have race conditions. Similarly, you are not guaranteed thread safety for subtypes of `AbstractArray`, like `BitVector`.